# upload aem package not working AEM 6.1

Tags: aem

I have an aem project in eclipse and built the package zip file by using maven autoInstallPackage command.

package was not uploaded either through maven build & deploy OR through CRXDE Lite package manager page.

**Error pop up while uploading through package manager page : "package file parameter is missing"**

I have done following suggestions 
1) In quickstart.bat , start.bat file I have added -Djava.io.tmpdir='C:\Users\name\Adobe\Author\temp" and made sure temp folder created

This change does not solve the issue.

The only way I got the package uploaded was, created "install" folder below crx-quickstart folder and copied the package zip file. Restarted the aem server.

It picked up the zip file and package got uploaded and I could see the bundle in installed status on admin console as bundle has some dependencies not resolved.

It looks like this is related to my project only, because I reinstalled 'cq-insights-content' zip file through package manager and it went through fine.

Environment: Windows OS, AEM 6.1, Java 1.8, IE, Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out, this issue seems to be related to a missing/full `tmp` directory.

Make sure that the directory specified in `java.io.tmpdir` is accessible by the user running your AEM process (r+w permissions).

More information:

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2335987

https://www.jethrocarr.com/2015/02/21/aemcq-5-6-1-package-file-parameter-missing/

Comment: I appreciate your response, If file permissions is the issue, why   reinstalling of "cq-insights-content" package worked through package manager? BTW, I did go through those links earlier.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out in VM the package upload is not working, but on a regular local physical machine it works. Not sure why it does not work in VM though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As you have mentioned, this indicates some issue with the package you had created.

Enable the debug level log for package install to get the details of what goes wrong with your package
org.apache.jackrabbit.vault.packaging.impl

Lastly, you can try to upload a new package instead of reinstalling an already uploaded package to check if anything in the VM is causing issue for all new package uploads. A standard package you could use for its is the ACS commons utility available at

[ACS AEM Commons](https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/)